# Avoiding executing an event when component value is changed

Tags: java

I am facing a problem with DropBox component, assuming that I've a dropbox which has an event which will be executed when its value changed by the user. but when I set the value of this dropbox internally the event occur automatically and the code in that event is executed which I don't want, I just want to set the value in the DropBox without executing the code in the it's event.
I'm using **setSelectedItem** Method to change the DropBox value Internally.
How can do this?

Comment: We'd probably need to see some code and a link to the library/api you're using. There _might_ be some method to call that doesn't cause events to be fired or you might be able to add some info to the event and if that info is present your handler just ignores it.

Comment: Create a class level boolean variable to track whether the change is "internal" or not.  Set the flag, change the value, then reset the flag.  In your event handler, only execute the code if the flag is not set.

Comment: Thanks, I did that